# prevent DOM from loading if array is null

Tags: angular, ionic2

In the html of the component I have the following:

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let recipe of recipeListRef$ | async">
....
<button *ngIf="isExistingFavorite(recipe)">
....
</ion-card>
```

that method searches through the favorites array:

```
isExistingFavorite(recipe: Recipe) {
for(let f of this.favorites){
  if(f.title === recipe.title){
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
```

the favorites array is loaded in the constructor:

```
favorites: Recipe[];

constructor() {
  this.favoritesService.getFavorites()
    .subscribe(
      favorites => {
        this.favorites = favorites;
      }
    );
}
```

the issue is that the page loads before the 'favorites' array is populated, and this results in the page crashing due to the array being null.

I am looking for a way to populate the array first, and then load the html.

**~UPDATE~**
I have added the following in the component but in the case that the user is authenticated, it always rejects although none of the console.logs print out at all...

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  if(this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
    this.favoritesService.getFavorites()
      .subscribe(
        favorites => {
          console.log('got the data', favorites);
          this.favorites = favorites;
          resolve(favorites);
        },
        error => {
          console.log('failed to get data', error);
          reject(error);
        }
      );
  }else{
    resolve(true);
  }
});
```

here is the getFavorites() service component:

```
  favoriteListRef$: FirebaseListObservable<Recipe[]>;

constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.favoriteListRef$ = this.database.list('myUrl', { preserveSnapshot: true});
}
}

getFavorites() {
  return this.favoriteListRef$;
}
```

Comment: just set it to empty in the beginning. `favorites: Recipe[]=[];`

Comment: @suraj yes, but that only returns an empty array, which results in the isExistingFavorite() method to return false every time.

Answer (score 1):

If a variable that is expected to be defined is undefined at some point, it should either have initial value:

```
favorites: Recipe[] = [];
```

Or additional check should be performed in places where it is expected to be defined:

```
isExistingFavorite(recipe: Recipe) {
  if (!this.favorites)
    return;

  for(let f of this.favorites){
  ...
```

The idiomatic way to solve this in Angular is to move `getFavorites` request to route resolver, so the array is already available as `activatedRoute.snapshot.data['favorites']` when route component is instantiated.

The alternative to route resolver in Ionic is [`ionViewCanEnter` hook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWYhR4Qo0PE).

A way that will work for both raw Angular and Ionic is to provide additional guard to the template:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="favorites">
  <ion-card ...>...</ion-card>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I believe ionViewCanEnter is what I'm looking for. I have incorporated it in my code but having an issue. Please check my edit in the original post.

Comment: If it rejects, you can chain the promise with `catch` and check what's the rejection and then track it back. But from the code you've posted, I don't see what can be wrong here.

Comment: it is saying _favoriteListRef$_ is undefined

Comment: That sounds strange, because in your code it's defined. Any way, that's something, I guess. Also, the errors in promise construction function should be caught with `try..catch`, in addition to `catch()`.